# What can cause a 'Static' label visible without WS_VISIBLE on windows

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I'm trying to pragmatically find a static label from some similar programs. I find one of the static labels don't have 'WS_VISIBLE' style but are still visible on one of the programs.

So what can cause a static label visible without 'WS_VISIBLE' style? And how can I distinguish it from other labels which are not visible without 'WS_VISIBLE'?

---

I write a sample code to reproduce the case, but failed.

```
TEST_METHOD(ShouldSetWindowsLong) {
    auto handle = HWND(0x00180BDC); // A handle to another similar visible Static
    auto style = (DWORD)::GetWindowLong(handle, GWL_STYLE);
    style &= ~WS_VISIBLE;
    ::SetWindowLong(handle, GWL_STYLE, style);
}
```

After running above code, the 'Static' label doesn't have 'WS_STYLE' and is not visible any more.

Comment: Another possibility is that the text you see is not being drawn by the static control, but by somebody else. The invisible static label is there for accessibility.

Comment: Don't quit understand, I was using SPY++ to find those problems. What I saw is a Static label contains visible text, but don't have WS_VISIBLE.

Comment: You found an invisible static control, so its text is not being drawn. But maybe somebody *else* is drawing the text.

Comment: You never even mentioned, which **problem** you are trying to solve. Just that your proposed solution ain't. If you want to randomly break other applications, there are easier ways to accomplish this.

Comment: Thanks @RaymondChen, I got a chance to look at the problem today, I changed the text of the Static control, but the UI didn't change. I think you are right, something else draws the text.

Answer (score 0):

> So what can cause a static label visible without 'WS_VISIBLE' style?

The WS_VISIBLE style can be turned on and off by [SetWindowLong](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633591(v=vs.85).aspx) without affecting visibility. Calling [ShowWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545(v=vs.85).aspx), [ShowWindowAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633549(v=vs.85).aspx), or [SetWindowPos](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545(v=vs.85).aspx) will set the WS_VISIBLE flag to reflect the actual visibility.

> And how can I distinguish it from other labels which are not visible
>   without 'WS_VISIBLE'?

Programmatically, you can't if you do not control that window.

Comment: So, if this is the case, then it is possibly that the 'Static' is initially visible but later 'WS_VISIBLE' is removed by 'SetWindowsLog'. I will write a sample code to prove it.

Comment: Seems SetWindowLong is affecting visibility!

Comment: Good news. Windows is evolving, despite what the docs say: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644898(v=vs.85).aspx  "Certain window data is cached, so changes you make using SetWindowLongPtr will not take effect until you call the SetWindowPos function."

Comment: :( Neither SetWindowLong nor SetWindowLongPtr could reproduce the case on Win 10.